# Declaring variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When do I know when to declare a variable and not to in Ruby?

I would like to know why the first code needs input to be declared as a string and outside of the block, while the second block doesn't.

```
input = ''
while input != 'bye'
  puts input
  input = gets.chomp
end
puts 'Come again soon!'
```

versus:

```
while true
  input = gets.chomp
  puts input 
  if input == 'bye'
    break 
  end
end
puts 'Come again soon!'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No variable is ever declared in Ruby.  Rather, the rule is that a variable must appear in an assignment before it is used.

Look at the first two lines in your first example:

```
input = ''
while input != 'bye'
```

The `while` condition uses the variable `input`.  Therefore the assignment is necessary before it.  In the second example:

```
while true
  input = gets.chomp
  puts input
```

Again, the variable `input` is assigned before it is used in the `puts` call.  All is right with the world in both examples.

Comment: this is not *exactly* right depending on your definition of "assigned".  Contrast `if (false) then a = 3 end; a || 3` with `b || 3`.  If you define "assigned" as upon any path of execution read by the interpreter then yes, but otherwise it's variables can never be used before they are allocated by the interpreter.

Comment: Preciate it Gene, it makes sense now!!

Comment: @KristopherMicinski  Fair enough.  Should have said "appear in an assignment", so made that edit.

Comment: Note that you can't do `foo += bar` for an assignment because in `foo = foo + bar`, the second `foo` is not assigned yet. So you get `undefined method +` error.